# KeyAdapter and KeyEvent is not working in Java, what to do?

Tags: java, overriding, keyevent

So I was trying to make a snake game using the help of BroCode, a youtube channel. I copied the exact same code first to learn but the getkeycode is not working. Means I am pressing the left, right, up, down key but the snake isn't moving. The move function is the same as the video. Here is the move function-

```
public void move() {
        for(int i=bp; i>0; i--) { //bp means snake body parts
            x[i] = x[i-1];
            y[i] = y[i-1];
        }
        
        switch(dir) {
        case 'U':
            y[0] = y[0]-us;
            break;
        case 'D':
            y[0] = y[0]+us;
            break;
        case 'L':
            x[0] = x[0]-us;
            break;
        case 'R':
            x[0] = x[0]+us;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Another problem is in the video, after making an inner class extending KeyAdapter, an @Override is there before the keypressed method, but when I try to use it, it gives me an error, the error only goes away when I remove the @Override. I checked on internet that whenever someone use this getkeycode or keyevent methods, there is always the @Override in there. This code is from the internet that I checked, here they used @Override and there is no error-

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
  {
    e.consume();
  }
}
```

So is that the real problem? Is that why the snake isn't moving?
My code where I tried to get the keypressed is shown below-
**Code**

```
public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter{

        public void keypressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                if(dir != 'R') {
                dir = 'L';
                break;}
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                if(dir != 'L') {
                dir = 'R';
                break;}
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                if(dir != 'D') {
                dir = 'U';
                break;}
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                if(dir != 'U') {
                dir = 'D';
                break;}
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(running) {
            move();
            checkApple();
            checkCol();
        }
        repaint();
    }
```

This project is so important to me, I have to do this one. Can somebody help me please? I really don't understand why the snake isn't moving when I pressed the key. I tried it with WASD keys too, still it didn't work.

Comment: Java is case sensitive. Compare the method declaration and **method name** in your 2nd and 3rd code block. Do you see any difference? Also, `@Override` is your friend.

Comment: The 2nd code block is from the internet, that isn’t my code. And what do you mean by "@Override is your friend."?  I did try to do a Override but it gave me an error. So I had to remove it. But the video I followed, he didn't remove the Override, still there wasn't any error.

Comment: As @maloomeister says java is case sensitive. Probably `keypressed` should be `keyPressed` and also should wear `@Override` because is overriden. And if is not - the compiler will tell you ;-)

Comment: Yes, the `Override` keyword gave you an error and you should have read what it said. The `Override` keyword tells the compiler "_Hey, I want to override a method, make sure that that method actually exists_". The compiler told you back "_I don't know the method `public void keypressed`, so that might be wrong_". And the compiler was right, because it should be `public void keyPressed` instead.

Comment: Hmm.. now that you mentioned, the video actually showed keyPressed, but I write keypressed. Is keyPressed some sort of a build in something? I thought I can name a method whatever I want. Anyway, I am checking it right now, I'll let you guys know as soon as possible!

Comment: @Newbie_programmer I suppose the best way to start for you is to look through the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), because it seems like you are missing the very basics of java / OOP.

Comment: Yes.. I learned Java many days ago. Maybe I forgot so many basic stuff! Anyway, @maloomeister much much appreciate the help. It worked.. Can't thank you both enough..

Comment: You should check out [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as a better alternative to KeyListener.

Comment: @WJS I'll check it out, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a `}` wrong.

```
 WRONG: case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                if(dir != 'R') {
                dir = 'L';
                break;}

  RIGHT  case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                if(dir != 'R') {
                dir = 'L';
                }
                break;
```